# How to use keypress event correctly

Tags: javascript

I have this code working perfectly fine with mouse click events.

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.myclass');

for(var i=0; i < nodes.length; i++){
    var node = nodes[i];
    node.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if(this.className == 'sample') {
            document.getElementById("massage").innerHTML="Hello";
        }       
    }, false);
}
```

Now if I just replace `'click'` with `'keypress'` all small letters, then the event is not triggered. What is the correct approach to do it.

And If I want to use Lambda's then what is the correct approach for the same task?

```
document.querySelectorAll('.myclass').addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
   document.addEventListener('keypress', ({ key }) => {      
        if(this.className == 'sample') {
            document.getElementById("massage").innerHTML="Hello";
        }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) says do not use `keypress` any more. Also says it does not work for all key presses. Also it is for KEY press, not mouse CLICK. Different events!

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using keypress for mouse?

This is what i got from your snippet

```
let el = document.querySelectorAll('.myclass');
let massage = document.getElementById('massage');

for(let i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
    el[i].addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
        e.target.classList.add('is-hover');
    })
    el[i].addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
        e.target.classList.remove('is-hover');
    })
}

document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
        if (el[i].classList.contains('sample') && el[i].classList.contains('is-hover')){
            massage.innerHTML = 'Hello';
        }
    }
})
```